# Capturing mobile phone traffic on wireshark when Android device is set up as AP

Tags: android, wireshark, access-point

I have set up my Android as AP and connected it to my machine and enabled also USB tethering.
I tested simple traffic on the Access point and no capturing were located on wireshark.
Am I missing something , It seems I can not capture the AP traffic on the Desktop PC. How Can I make to move the traffic to the desktop and capture the network traffic.

Thanks

Comment: Your question seems to miss a lot of details: 1) How did you set up the phone as AP? 2) Does the network use encryption? 3) Does phone network driver support promiscuous mode?

Comment: 1. Yes I set up my Android phone as AP. 2. no my network do nto use encryption. 3. How do I check it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22584259/435706  if you use your android as wifi ap then let your computer join it and follow that guide

Answer (score 1):

wire shark version :1.10.6
packets are getting captured ref : attached snap shot.
Probably something needs to be tweaked to view this packets.
However when i stop the capture using "red" button;you can save the captured data in  .lnk file on desktop or some location after which, reopening the file will get the details of all the captured data.

good luck

Comment: Thanks on the comment, But I refer to capturing traffic on Android.