# How to see network packets in Android?

Tags: android, wireshark, network-analysis

I am looking to see when and which apps are accessing the network from my Android Phone. I am looking for something like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org) but for Android. I found [Shark for Root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.n3o.shark) but it requires a rooted phone, I dont have one.

Is there a way to see the network traffic from each app?

Comment: Could you proxy your phone via your computer and sniff the packets there?

Comment: you cannot packet sniff in linux without root

Comment: @user1406716 have you tried my answer, id you have and you liked it, please consider marking it as correct :)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot monitor your own network on the android phone without root, but here is how you can do it on a computer (doesn't require root)

If you are on a windows PC, try the following:

1. Install fiddler2
2. Open and go to Tools > Fiddler Options > Connections > check Allow Remote computers to connect
3. Optional - uncheck act as system proxy on startup (to prevent you from getting traffic from your pc)
4. Restart fiddler
5. Go to wifi settings > touch your connected wifi network for 4 seconds > choose modify network config > show advanced options > Proxy > Manual > hostname > YOURCOMPUTER NAME OR IP > Proxy port > 8888 (or what you set it to in fiddler2)
6. Enjoy

P.S. If you are on MAC there is charles, if you are on another O.S. you can search for "fiddler2  OS_NAME alternative"

Comment: A link to the same http://www.cantoni.org/2013/11/06/capture-android-web-traffic-fiddler

Comment: Wow, Thanks I was scared he'd come back and ask about HTTPS, it's too hard to explain, but this guide is amazing :)